# Postgres Aurora RDS password auth fails except with master user

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, aws-aurora

I can successfully connect to a Postgres Aurora server using the master password thru the SSH tunnel on the bastion host I have setup.

However, when I create any other users, I can't connect with them even tho all other things are the same configuration wise. I get a DB level auth error.

```
password authentication failed for user "SomeUser"
```

I've added the users using these queries.

```
CREATE USER SomeUser LOGIN ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'SoMePaSsWoRd';
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE postgres TO SomeUser;
ALTER USER SomeUser CREATEDB;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE postgres TO SomeUser;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO SomeUser;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO SomeUser;
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: The message returned to the unauthenticated user is intentionally vague.  Look in the log files (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.PostgreSQL.html) for a more complete message.

Answer (score 0):

Even tho PG is case sensitive in other cases, it requires lowercase usernames. Using a lower case name during login fixed the issue.

Comment: Nothing to do with lowercase or uppercase as PG is case sensitive you need put username under double quotes while connecting from psql client

Comment: @eComEvo: Wrong diagnosis, but right consequence. Use legal, lower-case identifiers exclusively in Postgres to avoid the need for double-quotes (and all kinds of confusion).